# why book collection is shows nothing in C# Console?

Tags: c#

I add a class called Book and add public properties to encapsulate and the private field. Have a method called "GET BOOKS" .create several book objects and add them to a book collection. I want to Test the class by instantiating the class in the Main method. Call the GetBooks method and loop through each book in the collection. but I got errors.

```
//Book class code ...   


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CPRG202.Module1.Encapsulation
{

  
  public class Book
  {
    //Private field
    private string ISBN ;
    private string  _title;
    private string _author;
    private decimal _price;

    //constractor overloading
    public Book() { }
    public Book( string isbn,string title,string author,decimal price)
    {
      this.Isbn = isbn;
     this.Author= author;
      this.Title = title;
      this.Price= price;

    }

    //public properties
    public string Isbn
    {
      get{ return ISBN; }
      set{ ISBN = value; }
    }
     public string Author
    {
      get { return _author; }
      set { _author = value; }
    }
    public string Title
    {
      get { return _title; }
      set { _title = value; }
    }
    public decimal Price
    {
      get { return _price; }
      set { _price = value; }
    }



    //Add Method
    static List<Book> books = new List<Book>();
    public static List<Book> GetBooks()
    {
       Book mybook1 = new Book();
      books.Add(mybook1);
      Book mybook2 = new Book();
      books.Add(mybook2);
      Book mybook3 = new Book();
      books.Add(mybook3);


      return books;
    }


  }
}



--------------------------------
//Main class


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CPRG202.Module1.Encapsulation
{
  class Program
  {
    private static IEnumerable<Book> books;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      TestAddData();
    
     

      foreach (Book book in books)
        
 


      {
        Console.WriteLine("Book Price is {0}, Book Title is {1}", book.Price,book.Title); 
      }
      Console.ReadLine();

    }

    public static void TestAddData()
    {
      List<Book> books = new List<Book>();
    
      Book mybook1 = new Book();

      mybook1.Isbn = "876-L876-b654";
      mybook1.Title = "The Black Swan";
      mybook1.Author = "Nassim Nicholas";
      mybook1.Price = 35.99m;

      Book mybook2 = new Book();
      mybook2.Isbn = "435-r123-b987";
      mybook2.Title = "City Of Lies";
      mybook2.Author = "Ramita Navai";
      mybook2.Price = 27.99m;

      Book mybook3 = new Book();
    
      mybook3.Isbn = "111-f456-v435";
      mybook3.Title = "How to win Friends & Influence People";
      mybook3.Author = "Dale Carnegie";
      mybook3.Price = 35.99m;
      
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: *"but I got errors"* - and what would those be? Please [edit] your question to add that information.

Comment: As a side-note, I'd strongly encourage you to read up on *object initializers* and *automatically implemented properties*. Both will help you to write more compact and readable code.

Comment: The collection in your foreach (`books`) is empty. `TestAddData()` isn't adding anything to that collection (the one that is scoped to the whole class, not the one scoped to the method, though you're not adding to either one anyways).

Answer (score 2):

You not added the objects in the list in TestAddData.

add the rows in the end of method TestAddData

```
books.Add(mybook1);
books.Add(mybook2);
books.Add(mybook3);
```

Comment: I think it should be `this.books`, because there is a duplicate `books` variable hiding the class-scoped variable. Or, do `this.books = books.AsEnumerable();` as the last line.

Comment: TestAddData is a static method. The compiler not will accept one try to access of one instance attribute  through "this."

Comment: Sorry, `Program.books`, not `this`, you're right.

Comment: But is not necessary declarete the variable List<Book> books in the method TestAddData

Comment: Yes, `List<Book> books` is declared inside the `TestAddData` method, but it's not accessible outside of that method. Later on in the `Main` method, when the foreach is used on `books` (the one that is an `IEnumerable<Book>`), that information won't be present.

Comment: Thank you everyone sorry for the late response.